# ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(string s)

Tags: asp.net-core

I have this method to generate token:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
        {
            var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(userForLoginDto.Username.ToLower(), userForLoginDto.Password);

            if(userFromRepo == null)
               return Unauthorized();

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username)
            };   

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return Ok(new{
                token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
            });

        }
```

When I call this API via postman :

> localhost:5000/api/auth/login
>
> In body username: "john", password: "password"

I got this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a
>   String. Parameter name: s System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(string s)

because of this line :

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));
```

Kindly help to fix this error.

Comment: Can you show your settings file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this error, it seems `_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value` return null.

For `_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token")`, you need to make sure your `appsettings.json` contains content below:

```
{
"AppSettings": {
    "Token": "This is Token"
},   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact error, I am using VS Code. I solved this issue by setting an environment variable called "tokenkey" this can be set in the terminal using the following:

```
dotnet user-secrets set "TokenKey" "super secret key" -p API/
```

my code below

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenKey"]));
```

if you are getting this error in production mode you will have to set the environment variable on your server.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error. I solved this issue by setting environment variable in my launch settings.json file, you could put yours in the appsettings.json file,
just make sure it contians like the sample code below

```
"environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "JWT_SECRET": "This is a secret or key for jwt",
    "JWT_ISSUER": "Auth"
  }
```

Comment: I believe there may be some security concerns having the key inside the launchSettings.json or appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error. I solved this issue by setting environment variable in my launch settings.json file, you could put yours in the appsettings.json file, just make sure it contians like the sample code below

{
"Jwt": {
"Key": "-Jadfgdfgdfgdgdewsdg",
"Issuer": "********.com.tr"
},

Answer (score -2):

to solve this problem
add new item -> select appsetting.json then add it to API
copy all content in appsetting.development.json to appsetting.json

the problem solved

Comment: Please elaborate on why You believe changing the location of Your appsettings to the developmen would affect the issue experience. E.g. how you recognize 's' as being ... in order to help the asker understand the problem instead of just giving a magic answer